# How to export customer details on the basis of the email ids present in a CSV using Hybris export

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

my problem statement is - to fetch the uid and name on the basis of uids(A CSV which has a list of uids) that I input.
 **Now this can be done by following query:**
_"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""Customer.csv"" );"
insert_update Customer;uid[unique=true];name;
"#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch( ""select {pk} from {Customer} where {uid} in ('testcustomer1@gmail.com','testhello1@gmail.com')"");"_
**The result in csv will be the following:**
*testcustomer1@gmail.com;Test1|Customer1

testhello1@gmail.com;Test|Hello*
**But**, the issue is that for 2 uids its easy, for **600k** customers if to fetch out of 1200k is tough. 
I have  a CSV of email ids from which I wish to refer here so that the list can be used directly somehow instead of manually adding 600k customers.
Kindly provide a solution for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an option to convert the CSV to a string like ('testcustomer1@gmail.com','testhello1@gmail.com') and just add the headers and the ending for the export ?

Comment: no, problem statement is we are provided with the CSV and have to use that without going through any
Cronjob/dao implementation
or manual addition of strings from csv

Comment: Why are you export all customer with impex and match them with you csv out of the hybris?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSVReader you can achieve the same.

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];...
                    "#% CSVReader reader = new CSVReader( ImpExManager.class.getResourceAsStream(""myDataFile.csv""), ""utf-8"" );"
                    "#% reader.setMaxBufferLines(100000l);"
                    "#% impex.includeExternalData( reader, 1, -1 );"
```

[For more details visit the help.hybris.com below link.](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/2fb5a2a780c94325b4a48ff62b36ab23.html)